# property of algebra

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

$C$ is a non-empty collection of subsets of a space $\Omega$.

Let $F(C)$ be the smallest algebra containing $C$. Show that for each $B\in F(C)$, there exists a finite subcollection $C'$ of $C$ such that $B\in F(C')$.

This is intuitively clear. What is an elegant solution?

This is not homework. I'm just interested.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the opposite: there exists some $B \in F(C)$ so that for any finite subcollection $C'$ of $C$, we have $B \notin F(C')$.  Write $\mathcal{B}$ for the subcollection of such sets.

Now consider $F(C) \setminus \mathcal{B}$ -- that is, consider the set of subsets in $F(C)$ and remove those in $\mathcal{B}$.  I claim that this collection of sets forms an algebra which contains $C$.  Certainly this algebra is smaller than $F(C)$ in contradiction to the hypothesis.

We need to show that $F(C) \setminus \mathcal{B}$ is closed under union, intersection, and complement.  Let $X, Y \in F(C) \setminus \mathcal{B}$.  There exist finite subcollections $C_X$, $C_Y$ of $C$ so that $X \in F(C_X), Y \in F(C_Y)$.  Clearly  $X \cup Y \in F(C_X \cup C_Y)$ and $X \cap Y \in F(C_X \cap C_Y)$.  Both $C_X \cup C_Y$ and $C_X \cap C_Y$ are finite.  By definition $X^c \in F(C_X)$.  Therefore $F(C) \setminus \mathcal{B}$ is an algebra of sets.